# Is there any way to see follower's cooldowns?

Tags: diablo-iii

My Barbarian loves cleaving skulls, but cleaving skulls is also dangerous because I am right in the middle of the action. The Templar follower has several heals at his disposal. They have a cooldown, although I don't know what it is exactly, and there have been several close calls (and a few unfortunate deaths) because I waited too long to use a health potion. I have wasted either a health potion and/or heals because I wasn't sure if he had a heal ready.

Is there any way to see the cooldowns for these abilities so I know if I can expect a heal or if I should drink a health potion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, no, there does not appear to be a way to check your follower's cooldown timers.

As far as I know, the portrait and the follower panel are the only methods of getting data about your follower's current status.

I tested this with my Templar, by giving him a bunch of active skills and then putting him in situations where he'd want to use them.  His portrait doesn't change at all, regardless of his ability states, and there's no indication on the follower panel that any of his skills have been used.

Comment: Bummer. That sounds like something that would be helpful for players. Here is to hoping they will add a way to see their cooldowns in the future!